# How to provide custom login error messages from custom user store manager?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is it possible (and how) to provide custom login error messages generated in the user store manager class?

I've created custom user store manager based on JDBCUserStoreManager class.
I've overriden doAuthenticate method, in which I'd like to provide the message why the authentication was not possible.

I see that doAuthenticate method can throw the UserStoreException so I thought it's a way to pass custom login error message, but I see my message only in the logging console.

thanks,
Krzysztof Polak

Answer (score 0):

Error message is shown by a UI component. To be precise, it is the org.wso2.carbon.ui component. This is coming from the carbon kernel. You will find a login.jsp in this component. When you follow it, you will see which method it is executing (Most probably AuthenticationAdmin client). Like this, you need to back track to see where you can use your error message which you pass from your user store manager.

You should be able to find the correct source code based on the product version you are using.